# ajax and multiple check boxes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

how to display multiple checkboxes value in ajax language?

Comment: There is no such language as "ajax" - it's just javascript.  And if you can do it in html, you can do it in javascript.

Comment: Can you please throw in three or four more sentences to describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: he should be voted up to provide any feedback to answers :)

Answer (score 1):

[**AJAX**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is a not a *language*, its more of a technique used on the client-side to create interactive applications on your webpage by using a group of *languages* such as JavaScript and PHP.

To display the values you can use HTML and JavaScript, look at [**Finding the value of an HTML form checkbox**](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/finding_the_value_of_a_checkbox.php3) or with PHP, HTML and JavaScript at [**PHP Example AJAX and MySQL**](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at **[PHP Ajax tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxphp.php)** :)

There are quite some ways you can create checkboxes:

**With PHP:**

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="whatever" />';
// and son on
```

**With Ajax Script:**

You could simply ajax response which contains raw html of checkboxes.

**With Javascript:**

```
var chk = document.createElement("input");
chk.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
var frm = document.forms[0];
frm.appendChild(chk);
// and on on........
```

But all of those things seem to be new to you, you should first read **[PHP Ajax tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxphp.php)**.